# Filter only products with date (stored as text) are not in past

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In table `{$wpdb->prefix}postmeta` I have optional custom product field `limit_time`. This field store datetime in specific format as text (ex. `8.12.2020 10:00` or `19.5.2021 11:30`). I need to create a filter in woocommerce so that only products that either do not have this attribute filled in or the specified date is in the future are displayed (exclude all products with this date in past).

However, I can't create the meta_query condition I need.

This way it is possible to convert that value in the database to a date, but I don't know how to use it in meta_query.

```sql
SELECT meta_value, STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%d.%m.%Y %h:%i') as meta_value_fix
  FROM `wordpress_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = 'limit_time'
```

This returning correct date `8.12.2020 10:45` `2020-12-08 10:45:00` but how to compare this calculated value with current datetime in functions.php?

Is it possible to use such a conversion here, with meta_query?

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'custom_woocommerce_filter' );
function custom_woocommerce_filter( $meta_query, $that ){
  $meta_query[] = array(
    'key'     => 'limit_time',
    'compare' => '>',
    'value'   => date("d.m.Y H:i"),
    'type'    => 'DATE' // NOT WORKING
  );
  return $meta_query;
}
```

Comment: what's the result comes with your query? empty or all products on site?

Comment: It is empty.. but there will be some deeper problem that I don't understand, because if I change the compane to `>=` it won't return anything either. it will probably end up with a silent error and just won't show the products.

Comment: You could change type to "DATETIME" for a try. WP_query only allowed `/^(?:BINARY|CHAR|DATE|DATETIME|SIGNED|UNSIGNED|TIME|NUMERIC(?:\(\d+(?:,\s?\d+)?\))?|DECIMAL(?:\(\d+(?:,\s?\d+)?\))?)$/` list below. If you have time part that put the appropriate type.

Comment: I tried, the result is still an empty list of products. I assume that DATETIME cannot extract the date in the format `d.m.Y H: i`. As a workaround, I can't change the format of that field, but I was able to add a new key that contains the date in the `YmdHi` format and I'm comparing it numerically there.. so it is working that way. However, I'm afraid meta_query can't do this.

Comment: It coud not. Check the `class-wp-meta-query.php` in WordPress core( woocommerce query use the native wp_query). in method `get_sql_for_clause` You could saw the native only declare the type below and didn't convert other formatted for DATE ..etc, MySql only allowed the US formatted(Y-m-D). The solution I reckon is create the left join and convert condition to your formatted to compare, that would be easier find out the solution Lol.

Comment: In addition, `wp_query` is collect the WHERE clauses with `CAST($meta_value as $meta_type)`. so unfortunately, it doesn't work.